# Trigger rule: NONE_FAILED_MIN_ONE_SUCCESS not working as expected

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I have a branch operator and that completed successfully. It then entered the branch which starts with "create tables" task. But that task failed. The Update_watermarks task is setup to be run with trigger "none_failed_min_one_success". As the tasks have failed, I expect that the update_watermarks task would not have gotten invoked, and yet it did.

Am I misunderstanding the trigger? or is there a bug?

[image: Example graph showing problem]

[Airflow Documentation - Trigger Rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules)

```
none_failed_min_one_success: All upstream tasks have not failed or upstream_failed, 
and at least one upstream task has succeeded.
```

[Airflow Trigger Rules: All you need to know!](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-trigger-rules-all-you-need-to-know/#:%7E:text=This%20is%20the%20rule%20you%20must%20use%20to%20handle%20the%20BranchPythonOperator%20pitfall)

Oddly, I tried it with none_failed and it still allowed the task to complete:
[image]

And the description for none_failed is

```
none_failed: All upstream tasks have not failed or upstream_failed -
that is, all upstream tasks have succeeded or been skipped
```

Using all_success seems to provide partially the behavior I am looking for:
[image]

But the problem is the last task does not get executed, when the branch is skipped!
[image]

Ideally, it feels like none_failed_min_one_success should be what I want:

1. If the branch operator or the tasks in the branch fail, then the last task should not run
2. If the branch operator succeeds and the branch task succeed the last task should run
3. If the branch operator succeeds and the branch tasks are skipped, it should still run the last task.